# Changing formula type so that values will update without reference Workbook being open

Tags: excel

I'm using the below formula to grab some data out of another workbook and calculate the average. It will only update when I have the other file open. is there a way to change this into an index formula or something that will update without having to open the other workbook? The formula is set up the way it is because the data starts off with "NA" in the first 1-5 cells so I need it to skip those. Thanks!

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET('S:\Projects\[Economic Data - Main - inverted data.xlsx]GDP - Real'!G$3,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER('S:\Projects\[Economic Data - Main - inverted data.xlsx]GDP - Real'!G$3:G$5000),)-1, ,2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replacement of the `OFFSET` with `INDEX` should be like this:

```
{=AVERAGE(INDEX('S:\Projects\[Economic Data - Main - inverted data.xlsx]GDP - Real'!G$3:G$5000,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER('S:\Projects\[Economic Data - Main - inverted data.xlsx]GDP - Real'!G$3:G$5000),)):INDEX('S:\Projects\[Economic Data - Main - inverted data.xlsx]GDP - Real'!G$3:G$5000,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER('S:\Projects\[Economic Data - Main - inverted data.xlsx]GDP - Real'!G$3:G$5000),)+1))}
```

This is only working as an array formula. So input it into the cell without the curly brackets and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter].

It will calculate the average of two cells. The first cell with a numeric value in `'S:\Projects\[Economic Data - Main - inverted data.xlsx]GDP - Real'!G$3:G$5000` and the cell after this.